# How to present JSON via a e.force:showToast event - escaping of curly brackets?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast

I have been wondering why a string of this form

```
ERROR on search state=ERROR error=[{"message":"System.QueryException: sObject type..."}]
```

displays like this:

> ERROR on search state=ERROR error=[]

when used as the `message` of a `e.force:showToast`.

Checking [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_showToast.htm), I see that the `messageTemplate` parameter supports the substitution of values via `{0}`, `{1}` etc and suspect that the same processing is being applied to the `message` i.e. the content between the curly brackets is assumed to be a numbered parameter to be substituted and so is discarded.

Assuming that, my question is how to escape the curly brackets. This Java MessageFormat escaping doesn't work:

```
m = m.replace('{', '\'{\'').replace('}', '\'}\'');
```

and neither do these:

```
m = m.replace('{', '\\{').replace('}', '\\}');
m = m.replace('{', '\{').replace('}', '\}');
```

Anyone found escaping that does work here?

**PS**

I'm discarding them for now:

```
m = m.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
```

Comment: Log a case with Salesforce; this is not expected behavior. I have a workaround for you, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have to literally use templating to get them to appear correctly:

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({title:"Success", 
                    message:"hello world",
                    messageTemplate:"{0}hello world{1}",
                    messageTemplateData: ["{","}"]})
        .fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Very sneaky ...

Answer (score 0):

Using sfdcfox's work around, this puts in the numbered placeholders:

```
m = m.replace('{', '_PLACE_KEEPER_').replace('}', '{1}').replace('_PLACE_KEEPER_', '{0}');
```

and note that you have to supply a non-empty `message` that the `messageTemplate`:

> Overwrites message string with the specified message